# Conditional statement inside for loop

Tags: javascript, if-statement, for-loop

II have a basic for loop to loop through a data feed:

`for(var i = 0; i<items.length; i++) {`

Then several variables are defined in this form:

`var x = items.content[i]`

Now I want to do something if one of the values of `x` equals a value from outside the loop (`y`):

`if (x == y) {
//do something
}`

All values of `x` and `y` will always be unique, so there can never be more than one match - but there may be none.

The problem comes next - I want to do something else if there is no match, if no value of `x` matches `y`.

If I just do something like:

`else {
//do something else
}`

the `else` condition is also satisfied by other values of `x`.  I have tried putting `break;` after the `if` condition, but unless the match is found on the first value of `x`, both conditions are satisfied and both actions are triggered.  How do I construct this so that the first action is triggered if there is a match between `x` and `y`, but the second action is triggered *only* if **all** values of `x` don't match `y`?

Thanks for any suggestions or advice.

Comment: You can declared one boolean at the top and mark it to TRUE if value matches, later you can refer that variable throughout your process surely :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a boolean that will hold the result of finding 'y', then execute the actions outside of the loop depending on that boolean:

```
var match = false;

for(var i = 0; i<items.length; i++) {
    var x = items.content[i]
    if(x == y) {
        match = true;
        // a match is found, there is no need to continue, 
        break;
    }
}

if(match) {
    //do something
} else {
    //do something else
}
```